# Can a verb end with 〜ます before the conjunction ので?

Tags: grammar

I know that you can end a verb with 〜ます at the end of a sentence. I also know that you can end a verb with 〜ます before the conjunction が.

So, what about [ので](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7)? Can you end a verb with with 〜ます before the conjunction ので?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can. ので is an explanatory particle, similar to から. ので after a ます form would be used to explain what will follow from it.  A quick google search for ますので yields several results, including a Japanese Stack Exchange Q&A:

[Can you use the polite form ます with ので?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15263/can-you-use-the-polite-form-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-with-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7)

https://mayonez.jp/topic/1020660

Comment: Hey, thanks! I should have realized that question had already been asked! Oops!