What form comes before ので
Genki I Chapter 12 says the part of ので sentence is USUALLY in a short form. All examples are given in short form until I found an example in JLPT sensei website:
今から行きますので、少々お待ちください。
Shouldn't it be
今から行くので、少々お待ちください。
My question is what form exactly comes before ので?

「行くので」, 「行きますので」, 「行ったので」, 「行きましたので」 are all grammatically correct. See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15263/.

The word "usually" implies there are exceptions. In your case, the key point is that this is in honorific language, and the speaker is talking to someone of higher status, such as your boss, teacher, or a guest. In such cases, using the polite ending (ます) before ので is usually fine, and it's sometimes even desirable.
In honorific speech, whether you should use ます before ので depends on several factors.

The level of politeness matters. If you have to speak like a clerk of a luxury hotel, you probably need to say 今から参りますので (参る is the humble version of 行く). But if you are talking to a business partner you have worked with for years, something like 今から行くんでお待ちください may suffice.
When the speaker's or listener's own action comes before ので, it is often expressed in the polite form. But something like 明日は雨が降るので or 今日は暑いので can be said without ます/です.


"ので", it's common to use the plain form of verbs or adjectives. In the case of verbs, it can be either the plain form (dictionary form/jishokei) or the masu-kei(ます形).
The first sentence, "今から行くので、少々お待ちください。", uses the verb "行く" (iku) in its plain form, followed by the explanatory particle "ので" (node), which indicates a reason or explanation. This sentence structure is casual and straightforward.
The second sentence, "今から行きますので、少々お待ちください。", uses the verb "行きます" (ikimasu) in its polite form, followed by the explanatory particle "ので" (node). This sentence structure is more formal and polite.
Other usage will be:
Verb + ので

今から行きますので、
今から行くので、

Adjective［い］+ ので

彼女は忙しいので、今日のパーティーに参加できません。

Adjective［な］+ な + ので

彼は親切な人なので、みんなから好かれています。

Noun + な + ので

この町は便利な場所なので、住みやすいです。



Correct me if I make any mistakes.


Your second to last example should also be described as noun + な + ので, like the last (人 and 場所 are nouns). Although adjective [な] + な + ので is possible, e.g.: ここは安全なので、～

I think this doesn't necessarily have to be a rule, means "because" in english. In english, before "because" there is any rule?
we're talking about time, "because I'm going now, you could wait a while".
but, if the person is impatient, "今行くので、待ってください”.
”少々”This word is indicating that you are being patient, then the right form will be ～ます
