# "Ungrammatical" 丁寧語 used by tour guides and museum narrators

Tags: etymology, politeness, dialects

I noticed on my trip to Japan that tour guides in museums etc use a very interesting type of language. It seems to be used almost exclusively by people in Osaka and Kyoto.

There are two features that stand out to me: the first one is that 〜ます seems to be used attributively very often. People say things like ここにありますもの and 〜ますので, while IIRC in standard Japanese ます does not have a 連体形. Forms like 〜まして, 〜ましょうと〜ます are also very commonly used, while supplantion by plain form is supposedly correct.

Secondly, people use けれども a *lot* and almost never use けれど or けど. This is not really "wrong", but I personally have never ever seen けれども in print. Obviously ど can be followed by も ever since Old Japanese, but 〜ども seems to be quite rare in Modern Japanese. Also, a weird invalid accent pattern seems to be used: けれども{LLLH}.

What is this type of 丁寧語 language? Is it a variant of 標準語 from Kansai area? I am sure that in situations where correct language is more mandated, like newscasting and text-to-speech train station announcements, this kind of "overgeneralized 丁寧語" is not used.

Comment: Just a note on the frequency of けれども: it has 23467 entries in the [BCCWJ](http://www.ninjal.ac.jp/english/products/bccwj/)

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11072/1478

Comment: Also related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15263/4914

Comment: けれども{HLHL} actually can have two stressed syllables. Further more, the last syllable of a phrase often gets  emphasized, which is a part of intonation rather than accent.

Comment: こういう話し方する人、多いですよね。いちいち語尾を上げて話す人。若者言葉かもしれませんが。「美しい日本語」とは見なされないので、真似しないほうがいいです。 [ビデオ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuluHicHcig)　from 1:20 「けれ[ども]{LH}～、け[ども]{LH}、～さ[んと]{LH}～、さ[んと]{LH}～、け[れど]{LH}～、ひ[とと]{LH}、～けれ[ども]{LH}～、けれ[ども]{LH}～」 from 3:37「あからさ[まに]{LH}～、きる[んで]{LH}～、とい[うか]{LH}～、が[わは]{LH}～、ききた[いし]{LH}～、ききた[いし]{LH}～、とか[言って]{LLH}～、ですけれ[ども]{LH}～、いらっ[しゃる]{LH}～、新聞[とか]{LH}～、方[だと]{LH}～・・・」

Comment: @Choko 若者言葉だけではなくて、ちょっと女っぽいしゃべり方と思わないか？

Comment: @DariusJahandarie そ～ですね～関西の女子がめっちゃ使ってそう・・・(実は私も知らないうちに言ってると思う。。)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ますので`is **not** wrong usage of grammar,but not appropriate.
It's called`「バカ丁寧」`

```
　　　このごろ毎晩、疲れて帰ってくるので、
　　　シャワーを浴びたあと、
　　　オンザロックを飲んでから
　　　軽い食事をして休むことにしています。
```

Words above are suitable for common use,words below are to much respection that sounds like a little foolish.

```
　　　このごろ毎晩、疲れて帰ってきますので、
　　　シャワーを浴びましたあと、
　　　オンザロックを飲みましてから
　　　軽い食事をしまして休むことにしております。
```