# Masu te-form with Kudasai?

Tags: grammar, verbs, politeness, て-form

Can you use the -masu te form to form requests? Like, can you say "machimashite kudasai"? (O.o sounds weird huh.)

Comment: User Locksleyu has a related article [**here**](http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2015/02/20/whats-with-the-japanese-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-form-mashite/) that says mashite and kudasai are not used together.

Comment: -て forms with ます are extremely rare, as it's almost never necessary to mess with the formality of verbs in subclauses.

Comment: @Sjiveru But I think that sometimes it's used in subordinate clauses when the matrix predicate is omitted, like if you compare そう言われても困り**ます** to そう言われ**まし**ても.  And of course it appears frequently in certain fixed expressions like はじめ**まし**て.

Comment: If you want a politer 待ってください, say お待ちください（ませ）.

Comment: @Sjiveru What about things like お手伝いくださいまして、ありがとうございました?

Comment: The second is an unusual (and probably unproductive) use; the first you could argue isn't a subclause ^_^

Answer (score 4):

～ましてください is ungrammatical, because *only one* (in most cases, *last*) *verb is allowed to take polite form per sentence* to make that sentence polite. Since ください is already the polite form of くれ (くださる < くれる), no other polite verbs allowed.

Strictly speaking, a sentence that consists of multiple [coordinate clauses](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryoflinguisticTerms/WhatIsACoordinateClause.htm) allows (or is recommended) to have polite form for each clause, because they are but independent sentences glued together. て indeed sometimes works as coordinate conjunction when it leads a clause, which may cause some confusion, but I could hardly think of a valid setting ～ましてください would separate into two clause at て.

> 東京の大学に行った**が**、故郷で就職した。 (only as coordinator)
> 東京の大学に（○ 行きました／× 行った）**が**、故郷で就職しました。
> *I went to college in Tokyo, **but** got a job in my hometown.*
>
> 東京の大学に行く**のに**、とてもお金がかかる。 (only as subordinator)
> 東京の大学に（× 行きます／○ 行く）**のに**、とてもお金がかかります。
> *It costs much money to (=**so that** I) go to college in Tokyo.*
>
> 東京にも行っ**て**、シアトルにも行った。
> 東京にも（○ 行きまし／○ 行っ）**て**、シアトルにも行きました。
> *I went to Tokyo, **as well as** (=**and** I went to) Seattle.*
>
> 東京に行っ**て**、人が変わっ**て**しまった。
> 東京に（× 行きまし／○ 行っ）**て**、人が（× 変わりまし／○ 変わっ）**て**しまいました。
> *He **has become** totally another man **since** he went to Tokyo.*

Answer (score 3):

Typically the "~mashite" form is only used for pretty specific cases, like phrases such as "hajimemashite" and sometimes in mid-sentence when speaking very politely.

But "~mashite kudasai" would be quite unnatural and I have never heard or seen this used before.

As rhyaeris has pointed out in a comment, I have [an article](http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2015/02/20/whats-with-the-japanese-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-form-mashite/) about this, so feel free to check it out if you like.

As a general rule, I think it is best for learners of Japanese to stick to a single "~mashite" per sentence, unless they have become extremely comfortable with a certain expression or form.